# Output listbox to multiple cells to use for autofilter array

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a multiselect listbox that users choose regions they want to filter in a dataset.

I currently output those selections into a single cell using this sub:

```
Dim listItems As String, i As Long
With RegionListBox
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then listItems = listItems & .List(i) & ", "
    Next i
End With

Range("AA1") = Left(listItems, Len(listItems) - 2)
```

At the end of the macro users run to update their workbook, I want to apply a filter using the values that I have output from the listbox. Currently this is how I do it:

```
Worksheets("4. Booking Summary").Range("$A$1:$G$1000" _
).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=(Range("$AA$1").Value),` Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as if users have selected multiple choices, the output in AA1 will be formatted like *"text, text, text"*. When it tries to apply this filter, it applies a text filter with that full string. For it to have the desired function it would need to filter using an array with each selected item.

I'm a bit stuck on how to achieve this. My thought was I need to output each listbox selection to a single cell, then set the autofilter criteria to an array referencing those cells. I'm just not sure how to do this. Happy for any suggestions.

Comment: `Criteria1:=Split(Range("$AA$1").Value,", ")` should do it

Comment: Tim, you're a champ. I had thought there must be a way I can split these values using a comma! It was right in front of me the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Split() to create an array:

```
Criteria1:=Split(Range("$AA$1").Value,", ")
```